# How could I deploy a shiny app created using shinyApp() via shinyapps::deployApp( )?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to deploy (to the web) an application made in R/Shiny by a call to the `shinyApp()` function.

It is possible to make an app by a call to `ShinyApp()` as follows:

```
 test_app = shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      numericInput("n", "n", 1),
      plotOutput("plot")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$plot <- renderPlot( plot(head(cars, input$n)) )
    }
  )
```

This retuns an object that represents the app and the app can run by printing that object. I wish to deploy the app that is made using`shinyapps::deployApp( test_app)` however that gives me the following error:

```
Error in shinyapps::deployApp(test_app) : 
  appDir must be a single element character vector
```

This is because the `deployApp` function is expecting a directory not a shinyApp object. Presumably the information to build and therefore deploy the app is contained in the `test_app` object, but inspecting that object does not reveal much, and it seems to be the same for any app I create:

```
>  str(test_app)
List of 4
 $ httpHandler     :function (req)  
 $ serverFuncSource:function ()  
 $ onStart         : NULL
 $ options         : list()
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.appobj"
>
```

The code to produce the app is not contained in any obvious way in that object. I suspect the answer may have something to do with R6 reference classes, which I do not understand.

Does anybody know how I might extract the information contained in the app from the `test_app` object in order to deploy it via the `deployApp()` function? (or an alternative approach)

I have posted this on the shinyApps users google group but got no response, so I'm trying again here.

Answer (score 2):

The `shinyApp` command is not meant to be used for app construction, from its' help:

> You generally shouldn't need to use these functions to create/run
>   applications; they are intended for interoperability purposes, such as
>   embedding Shiny apps inside a knitr document.

`deployApp` doesn't support `shinyApp` apps, as you probably found from `?deployApp`. That said, it's an easy fix for your (and most) apps, by more or less pasting your commands into files called `ui.R` and `server.R`, wrapped in `shinyUI()` and `shinyServer()`:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  numericInput("n", "n", 1),
  plotOutput("plot")
  )
)
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot( plot(head(cars, input$n)) )
  }
)
```

Put the two files in a directory and then run `deployApp("dir")` after testing with `runApp("dir")`

If you have parts of your shiny app that are not part of server or UI (ie data preprocessing), you will need to paste them above the shiny call in the relevant file. If you are calling you shiny app with arguments, you can either hard code them above your shiny call, or integrate them as reactive values in the shiny itself.

Comment: Thanks, but my real application is different from this test one (see here https://github.com/tomliptrot/predictshine). It creates an shiny app on the fly from within another R function, at the moment, it brings up that app on the browser. But I want to be able to save and deploy that app. I had seen that comment in teh help file, but I wondered if there might be a workaround...

Comment: I had a quick play with your app - see https://gist.github.com/jeremycg/a97a0f9837977d144a0c, or runGist("https://gist.github.com/jeremycg/a97a0f9837977d144a0c"). You just need to paste any non ui and server stuff at the top of your server.R and ui.R, as well as hard code any arguments you use. You could obviously make the armuents, labels etc. reactive, but that's a little more work.

Comment: obviously, not all of the stuff is needed in both ui.r and server.r, but this is a quick and dirty example